# Lagrangian of Rocket

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, rocket-science

While solving equation of rocket motion with Newton's law in 1-d,I pondered to apply Lagrangian method on this. However, I didn't get correct result.

Because I can eliminate last 2nd equation using last equation and get some other equation which is certainly not rockets motion.

The attempt is in screenshot

[image]

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the rocket has a time-dependent mass $m(t)$. Then its potential and kinetic energy are:

$$T=\frac{1}{2}m(t)\dot{x}^2$$

$$U=m(t)gx$$

Applying the Euler-Lagrange equation to these, and paying attention to the assumptions you impose on the time-dependence of the mass, will lead you to the correct equations of motion.